# non gaussian residual distribution for ARIMA

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, arima

I have a few theoretical and practical questions regarding residual distribution of ARIMA models.
I made quite a few for various purposes and I don't think I ever found gaussian distributed residuals.

Here is a small example.
The data contains 4080 observations of energy load in hourly resolution. You can see the average power generation in 1 hour resolution over a window of 150 hours (left figure) and the complete dataset (right figure)

[image: Average power generation in 1 hour resolution over a window of 150 hours (left figure) and the complete dataset (right figure)]

I generated an Arima model with R using the auto.arima() function of the forecast package. The result was an ARIMA(1 1 0) model, showing that the timeseries needed to be differenced once to be stationary (d value of 1).
I then used the auto arima result as a baseline and conducted a grid search for the best ARIMA model based on AICc. The grid search gave out an ARIMA(24,1,5).

[image]

As you can see, most of the residuals are very small and therefore the distribution density is very high around the numbers close to zero. So the residuals are not normally distributed. And to be honest, I don't see how that would ever be the case in any real data ARIMA model, because the better the model predicts the actual values the more residuals close to zero will be there.
Here are the Q-Q plots for both model residuals:

[image]

Although both models still show significant autocorrelation and better models can be found (possibly more complex models with higher p and q values), I see this kind of non normal residual distribution in all my ARIMA models, independant of the data I use.
Shouldn't ARIMA models yield normally distributed residuals in theory?
Is there a smart way to determine if the errors follow a different distribution (like t-distribution for example)?
Should I use a GARCH model?
Did anyone ever find an ARIMA model that worked with real data and yielded gaussian distributed residuals?
Are there tests I should check my original timeseries with before using ARIMA models, other than checking for stationiarity and autocorrelation?

One last curious thing I found is that if I use the ARIMA model to predict a test set, with small predcition sizes of only a 10-50 timesteps I get normally distributed errors and with increasing size the errors tend to start deviating from a normal distribution.

Comment: One suggestion is to try a seasonal ARMA model, since there is a clear periodic trend.

Comment: Related: [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima+normality-assumption).

Comment: @philbo_baggins They did, in a way (that's why $p=24$ seems to perform well). My guess is that `forecast::auto.arima` didn't pick that up because the `frequency` of the data isn't set correctly.

Comment: @philbo_baggins Yes, that was one of my thoughts as well. I tried a SARIMA model with a period of 24. I think it was (3 1 1) (1 0 1) 24 . Very similar results. Good prediction accuracy but non gaussian residual distribution.